# Flask Pagenation returns only one column of data error python

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am having `1000s` of data in MySQL. I am using `flask Pagenation` support to retrieve the data regarding the Page Number i gave.
But it returns only one column of data. 
I have five columns of data in MySQL. I want know how to retrive all the data from the page in a JSON format. Help me with some solutions

Here's the code i wrote:

```
@app.route('/listPDFfiles', methods=['GET', 'POST'], defaults={"page": 1})
@app.route('/listPDFfiles/<int:page>', methods=['GET'])
def listPDFfiles(page):
    try:
        page = page
        per_page = 5
        pdfFiles = Resume.query.filter_by(user_id=1).paginate(
            page, per_page, error_out=False)
        print(pdfFiles.total)  ===>(total page)
        print(pdfFiles.page)   ===>(page number)
        print(pdfFiles.items)  ===>(It returns only one column of data from MySQL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the Solution:

```
@app.route('/listPDFfiles', methods=['GET', 'POST'], defaults={"page": 1})
@app.route('/listPDFfiles/<int:page>', methods=['GET'])
def listPDFfiles(page):
        page = page
        per_page = 5
        a= []
        pdfFiles = Resume.query.filter_by(user_id=1).paginate(
            page, per_page, error_out=False)
        for i in pdfFiles.items:
            dd = {'id': i.id, 'data1': i.data1,
                  'data2': i.data2}
            a.append(dd)
        return jsonify({'success': 'true', 'message': a})
```