# Cannot find "items" attribute in Pagination in Flask

Tags: python, flask, pagination, flask-sqlalchemy

I am very new to Flask and pagination in general.

I need to paginate a list which is as follows:

```
campaign_brief_result = [
    {'id': 112233, 'name': 'DSR-335', 'description': 'Desc', 'currency': '0'},
    {'id': 11223344, 'name': 'DSR-336', 'description': 'Desc2', 'currency': '2'}
]
```

When I run the code below I am unable to find the items attribute. How can I access the data that is being paginated here?
Here is my code snippet that i am using:

```
paginated_data = Pagination( page = 1,
                             per_page = 2, 
                             total = len(campaign_brief_result),
                             search = False, 
                             record_name = 'campaign_brief_result')
print(dir(paginated_data))
```

the print shows me the following attributes of 'paginated_data':

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_get_single_page_link', 'alignment', 'anchor', 'args', 'bs_version', 'bulma_style', 'css_end_fmt', 'css_framework', 'current_page_fmt', 'display_msg', 'endpoint', 'first_page', 'format_number', 'format_total', 'found', 'gap_marker_fmt', 'has_next', 'has_prev', 'href', 'info', 'init_values', 'inner_window', 'is_disabled', 'last_page', 'link', 'link_css_fmt', 'link_size', 'links', 'next_disabled_page_fmt', 'next_label', 'next_page', 'next_page_fmt', 'outer_window', 'page', 'page_href', 'page_parameter', 'pages', 'per_page', 'per_page_parameter', 'prev_disabled_page_fmt', 'prev_label', 'prev_page', 'prev_page_fmt', 'record_name', 'search', 'search_msg', 'show_single_page', 'single_page', 'skip', 'total', 'total_pages', 'url_coding']
```

Comment: I dont know how to do this but this post seems to be how this works  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57848808/flask-pagenation-returns-only-one-column-of-data-error-python

Comment: Thanks @PeterMoore this helped. have a cookie :)

Comment: Thank you munch munch or you could like every post I ever did hehe.